# CSS or Javascript Solution to Horizontal Table Overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have a UI problem that I can't figure out a good interactive solution for. I have an html table node that has data that makes the table overflow out of the body. I need the table to basically scroll horizontally and stay within the body / viewpoint, but I'm looking for a better solution other than a bad scroll bar with an overflow-y. If you know of any js or css solution that isn't from the 90's that would get you 10 brownie points.

Comment: it's all about css. (css tag missing) you need something like that overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap;text-overflow:ellipsis;on your td.

Comment: What's wrong with overflowing the content?

Comment: I would suggest using a library instead of trying to solve this yourself. I've used both datatables.net and jqGrid (http://www.trirand.com/); I'm sure there are others.

Comment: If overflow isn't to your personal liking, why don't you describe what you DO want?

Comment: this is very doable without javascript but post some html or jsfiddle

Comment: I want a solution similar to scrolling, but not scrolling at all. cocco might have the most reasonable solution here, but I would love something more interactive and responsive.

Comment: I would post a picture but it wont let me since I dont have any rep points. But imagine a table overflowing out of the body, as a table will do.

Comment: You can link to an external image hosting site, such as Photobucket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any visuals of what you would consider better than "a bad scroll bar with an overflow-y", there's not much we can do to help you except take shots in the dark.

That said, what you seem to be asking for is exactly what overflow-y is for. You want it to scroll while being constrained to the container. That's definition of `overflow-y: scroll|auto`.

You can then use a JavaScript library to style the scrollbar, so you don't get the not-always-so-pretty system scrollbar. Here are a few you can try:

- [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/)
- [Tiny Scrollbar](http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/)
- [Slimscroll](http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll)
- [CSS (Webkit only, though)](http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/)
- [More options, courtesy Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=style+scrollbar&oq=style+scrollbar&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.3209j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#fp=a08d424211b95227&q=style+scrollbar)

Comment: I'm not looking for a scroll bar solution. I'm trying to think out of the box here. But yes, that would be a typical answer.

Comment: @RobertW.GreeneJr. - As I stated, you're going to have to elaborate more on what you *are* looking for (ideally with some kind of imagery), otherwise a) we won't be able to help you, and b) your question will likely be closed as some form of "unanswerable" (likely "not a real question" or "not constructive").